# Javascript chain a asynchronous image resize function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am using this [lib](https://github.com/MickL/JS-ImageResizer) to resize and compress images before upload

I resize my images like this:

```
var imgOne = $('#u-fileUpload-1')[0].files[0];
var imgTwo = $('#u-fileUpload-2')[0].files[0];

      if (imgOne !== undefined) {
        ImageResizer.resizeImage(imgOne, resizeOptions, function(result) {
          _this.imgArray.push(result);
        });
      }

      if (imgTwo !== undefined) {
        ImageResizer.resizeImage(imgTwo, resizeOptions, function(result) {
          _this.imgArray.push(result);
        });
      }
```

I resize my images and store them in a array called `imgArray`
The only problem is that these functions are asynchronous. So my code ends up posting/uploading the form with `imgArray` being empty since the resize functions has not finished.

So is there any way to chain these functions or check when they both is done?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: You know what asynchronous is, you know the functions are async.. yet you didn't post the code that uses this array that you're populating. So the question is - why? Why was that code left out and why would you try to mix sync/async together?

Comment: Implement it with Promises And use Promise.all success callback to post the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a function that just takes an array of images to resize and a callback:

```
function resizeImages(imgs, callback) {
    var resizedImages = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        ImageResizer.resizeImage(imgs[i], resizeOptions, function(result) {
            resizedImages.push(result);
            if (resizedImages.length === imgs.length) {
                callback(resizedImages);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
var imgOne = $('#u-fileUpload-1')[0].files[0];
var imgTwo = $('#u-fileUpload-2')[0].files[0];

resizeImages([imgOne, imgTwo], function(resizedImages) {
    //do work with resizedImages
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle it as an array of async functions (promises) [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
let imgArr = [img1,img2, ..... ];

var resizeArr = [];
imgArr.forEach(img => {
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      (function(cImg){
         ImageResizer.resizeImage(cImg, resizeOptions, function(result) {
            resolve(result);
         });
      })(img);
    });
    resizeArr.push(p);
})

Promise.all(resizeArr).then(resizedImgs => {
   //process new images
})
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fhwd1grg/)